# Help with Notation Concerning Bifurcation/Assimilation of Sequence Elements

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation, fractals

There have been a couple problems I've recently thought about that would benefit from having a certain way of notating the underlying process.  Say we have a sequence of sequences $\{a_n\}_m$, $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$, that follow that pattern described below:

$$
\{a_n\}_1=\{a_1^1,a_2^1,a_3^1,a_4^1,\cdots\}
$$

where the "exponent" denotes that these elements are part of the first sequence. To continue, the second sequence is **almost the same** as the first sequence, only some of the terms "divide" (bifurcate), so maybe $a_1^2=a_1^1$ and $a_2^1=a_2^2+a_3^2$ and for $n>3$,  $a_n^2 = a_{n-1}^1$

$$
\{a_n\}_2=\{a_1^2,a_2^2,a_3^2,a_4^2,a_5^2,\cdots\}=\{a_1^1,a_2^2,a_3^2,a_3^1,a_4^1,\cdots\}
$$

Now, there's also the opposite: some terms might **combine** (assimilate) together going to the next sequence.  So, $a_i^2=a_n^1+a_{n+1}^1$ for some $i, n$.  It is sort of like a fractal where the next sequence either draws in or out from the previous sequence. Does anyone have a convenient/compact way of notating this behavior?